# Windows Phone 7 onDraw

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xna

I am developing a game. I would like to draw a couple of textures on the screen. I succesfully achieved that by drawing texture2d using spriteBatch.

The thing is the textures are displayed only if I put the code in the onDraw method. The onDraw method is bound to the timer so it executes many times. I would like to draw my rectangles only once.

When I put the code in the constructor the rectangles are not displayed - they show up only when I put the code in the onDraw function. How can I omit that?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really any sensible option for doing this in XNA. Most games want to re-draw the entire screen each frame - so that is how XNA is structured. (And, without a *really* compelling reason, this is how you should structure your game too.)

XNA is double-buffered (I don't think there's a way to turn that off). You do your drawing on the back-buffer and then swap it with the front buffer. You never draw to the screen directly.

So, while you don't *have* to clear the screen and re-draw it on each frame, if you don't you must manually keep the contents of these two buffers in-sync - otherwise you will get severe flickering. This is not worth the effort.

What you *may* be looking for is the `Game.SupressDraw` method (call it from `Update` - or - as an alternative: override `BeginDraw` and return `false`). This will prevent `Draw` from being called for that particular frame, and prevent the back-buffer from being swapped to the front. So the previous frame simply stays on-screen.

But it's generally easier to simply draw every single frame.